# Remove first space if string contains exactly 2 spaces

Tags: string, space, spaces

I'm having issues when trying to remove the first space of a string if that string has 2 spaces in it. For example it should be turning "Fully Functional Method" into "FullyFunctional Method", but "Functional Method" should not be changed because it only has 1 space. I can't really think of a way to remove first space if the string contains 2 spaces.

Comment: Which language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but you may search into [RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html) and String.[replace()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace()) to replace some stuff in a String.
Here is another link to understand the [Characters, metacharacters, and metasequences](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e91.html).

```
var myPattern1:RegExp = /  /g;  
var str1:String = "This  is  a  string  that  contains  double spaces.";
trace(str1.replace(myPattern1, " "));
//this replaces all "  " by " "...
//outputs : This is a string that contains double spaces.
```

Or in your case (I suppose) something like this

```
var myPattern2:RegExp = / /;  
var str2:String = "Fully Functional Method";
trace(str2.replace(myPattern2, ""));
//If you omit the g, only the first space will be replaced by ""
//outputs : FullyFunctional Method
```

There is so much things you can do by using RegExp, that I will not explain this here...
Just check on the Adobe website...
This is a quick and efficient way to work on Strings.
I hope this will help.
Since you check at those links, you will understand that my example is pure rough and should be modified to have a FullyFunctional Method. :D

Comment: AMO, RegExp this is the best way to deal with Strings by avoiding long and unnecessary loops that may cause "slow-downs" in your code.
Especially if you work on large Strings. The RegExp Class is a little surprising at glance, but when you're familiar with the syntax, this is the best and more efficient way to deal with Strings.
I will not down vote other people answers, but I think that you should avoid unnecessary loops... :\

Keep it simple :D

Comment: @Daniel Holler You didn't tell if it was useless nor useful...
Did you try to check to the Regexp doc?

Answer (score 0):

Do a linear scan through the string. Count the number of spaces and record the index of the first space, if any. If there are two spaces, return a string that is the concatenation of the characters up to but not including the first space, and the characters after the first space.

Keep it simple. It is possible to solve your problem with regex, but keep in mind that the worst case time complexity of finding a particular character in an unsorted set is always going to be O(N), so it won't be faster.